What is the impact on prices and employment of higher wages won by trade unions in monopsony labour markets (compensation not equal to MRP)?
One of the most common objections to labour unions is that they increase prices for the consumer, but does this occur in situations where the non-competitive nature of a particular labour market means that workers are paid less than their marginal revenue product, that is, less than the competitive equilibrium?
